# How do I remove a domino from the screen?

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a domino game in java. At the start of the game the player receives 7 dominoes. This is called his "hand". So the players sees these 7 dominoes on the screen. I use the following code to display the dominoes in the players hand:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("images\\5-5.png");
Image image = imageIcon.getImage(); 
Image newimg = image.getScaledInstance(60, 120,java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);  
imageIcon = new ImageIcon(newimg);

JLabel img = new JLabel(imageIcon);
img.setBounds(100, 100, 60, 120);
getContentPane().add(img);
```

But when a player plays a domino, the domino must be removed from his hand and placed on the board. How do I remove a domino from a hand? That is, how do I remove the above domino graphic from the screen?

Comment: `remove(img)` Ideally you would map the domino's logical value with the icon.

Comment: Don't store the state in the UI. Have a separete Domino Model, remove the piece in that model, then redraw the entire UI.

Comment: In [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801887/deleting-a-line-in-java-when-using-paintgraphics-p/50802633#50802633) doesn't remove exactly a domino, but uses the same principle to change the visibility of a line. However I must also tell you don't use `null-layout` and / or `setBounds`. It might bring more bugs than you expect. For better help sooner post a [mcve]